# Delete unnecessary empty row from file with PHP

Tags: php

This code is working for me. In this case result is in one row, but there is 2nd row what is empty. I need to know how to edit file and do backspace from last point in file, so i can get only one row, because other part of code I hope i have describe clearly .

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row['mac'];
}

if($h = fopen('mac.txt', 'a')) {
    fputcsv($h,$data);
    fclose($h);
}
```

Comment: please run `var_dump($data)` and post the contents

Comment: Contents is array : 
array (size=4)
  0 => string '00:AA:BB:09:13:F4' (length=17)
  1 => string '00:AA:BB:00:90:69' (length=17)
  2 => string '00:AA:BB:00:91:A2' (length=17)
  3 => string '00:AA:BB:00:91:CC' (length=17)

But content in file is like on screenshot : http://prntscr.com/8hpwzb

Comment: And i need this 2nd row to delete, because its making me problem in other part of code. Content of file need to be only in 1 row.